# How do I stretch a UI Element to fill the vertical space on a view?

Tags: android

I have a layout that contains three rows or segments in my Android view.

The first layout region has a fixed height based upon the content of the region with a:layout_height="wrap_content".

The next segment will contain a ListView with it's built in scrolling capability, I would like this to take up the available screen real-estate.

The final segment will always have a fixed height based upon an absolute value or a:layout_height="32dp".  I would like this thrid segment "docked" to the bottom of the view.

For reference the following XAML accomplishes what I want

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
       <RowDefinition Height="*" />
       <RowDefinition Height="32" />
   </Grid.RowDefinisions>
</Grid>
```

Is this possible via android layout XML?  And if so how can this be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent", 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
or 
    android:layout_weight="1".

The latter will take all of the remaining unused space in its parent layout, the former will sometimes force other elements out of view.

Comment: Never seen "match_parent" but android:layout_weight="1" along with android:height="0dp" did the trick.

Comment: If you're using api level 8 or above, use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html. It's the replacement.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible. You can do this many ways, the easiest of which in my opinion is to simply use a `LinearLayout`. Something like:

```
<LinearLayout layout_height="fill_parent">
    <firstitem layout_height="wrap_content" layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <ListView layout_height="fill_parent" layout_width="fill_parent" />
    <bottomitem layout_height="32dp" layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use `dp` not `sp`.  `sp` is generally for font sizes, `dp` for everything else.

By the way, here's a good [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html) to get you started with common layout objects.

Comment: Yeah - "dp" not "sp" that's what I meant :) good clarification

Comment: Just as an FYI - the XML in this answer was my original approach and it did not work.  The second "fill_parent" on the ListView item took the rest of the screen real-estate and pushed the bottom item off of the screen.

Comment: Ahh, I've seen that happen before sometimes. You'll want to use `layout_weight` as you noted then. I usually prefer `layout_height="wrap_content"` over `0dp`, but either should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried layout_width="fill_parent"?